# When calling a VBA Macro from a VBScript file download is not completed

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to automate the download of a file from a SharepointSite using VBA and VBScript. The problem is that when I call the Macro from the VBScript file dosen't seen to download correctly, no matter what size or type of file I'm trying to download it always saves it as 4kb file and it doesn't open, however, when I run the macro from the Excel it works fine, any ideas on how could this be solved or if I'm missing something.

This is the VBA code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit


Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Sub testdownload()

Dim FileURL As String
Dim DestinationFile As String


FileURL = "https://test.sharepoint.com/teams/test/28JUL23.xlsb"

DestinationFile = "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Test5.xlsb"

URLDownloadToFile 0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0

End Sub
```

and this is the code for the VBScript

```
  Dim xl
  Dim xlBook      
  Dim sCurPath
  MsgBox "Process Started"
  path = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
  Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(path & "\SharepointDownloadTest.xlsb", 0, True)   
  xl.Application.Visible = False
  xl.DisplayAlerts = False
  xl.Application.run "SharepointDownloadTest.xlsb!testdownload"
  xl.ActiveWindow.close
  xl.Quit
  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xl = Nothing
  MsgBox "Task Completed"
```

Any ideas on how to call the macro and succesfully download the file?

When I run the Macro from Excel it successfully download the file as seen below:

[image]

When I run the same Macro but from the VBScript, it downloads this:

[image]

Don't know what changes when it is run from the script

Comment: Your downloaded "excel file" is likely an HTML page saying something about the problem you're having.  Open it in a text editor and see what it says.